# Is there a public UDP site to test ObjC code?

Tags: ios, macos, udp

I'm attempting to learn UDP coding as a neophyte.

I've been doing iOS development for years and want to start learning to do some basic network coding using the UDP protocol.

Is there a practice site to play with where I can't do any harm?

Or... is it possible to merely wire up the Apache server that comes with OS X and work with that?

This is intended to be for an iOS environment so would at least have to work via simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Apache is an HTTP server, HTTP being a protocol built on TCP not UDP. You're probably going to be best off trying to write both a client and server that run in the same application and having them talk to each other via UDP.

FWIW, DNS is based on UDP, so talking to a public DNS server might be a good starting point.